# How to get the content of a tag with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML-file:

```
<ns1:book> <ns1:title>Harry Potter</ns1:title> <ns1:author>Rowling</ns1:author> </ns1:book>
```

With the help of XPath-query I want to get only content of teg `<title>`, here it is `Harry Potter` (not `<ns1:title>Harry Potter</ns1:title>`).
How can I do this? Is there any function for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/text()` after you have located an element.

Like: `//*[name()='ns1:title']/text()`

See the example [here](http://xpather.com/botZklgF)..

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax (not sure every XPath processor supports it though) :

```
//*:title/text()
```